# Properties of coefficients of ring spectra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology

This is an awkwardly backwards question, but bear with me here: Suppose I have a  graded ring $R$ with unit, which has an invertible element $u$ in degree $2$. The multiplicative formal group law $f(x,y) = x + y + u\,x\,y$ yields a homomorphism $MU_* \to R$. Suppose that I know the following things

- The functor $X \mapsto MU^*(X) \otimes_{MU_*} R$ is a multiplicative generalized cohomology theory (in particular, it is exact).
- The above functor is represented by an $E_{\infty}$-ring spectrum.

> What properties can I deduce from this about the ring $R$?

For example: Is it true that $R$ is torsion-free (in each degree)? I vaguely seem to remember that $K$-theory with mod p-coefficients does not have an $E_{\infty}$-ring structure, so this seems at least plausible. Does $R_0$ have to be a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ if I throw into the mix that $R_0$ is countable?

Comment: The reason that mod p K-theory doesn't have an $E_{\infty}$ structure is that p annihilates the unit and it is not a wedge of Eilenberg-MacLane spectra. So this does not rule out having torsion in higher degrees. I also see no reason that it would have to be a subring of the rationals, you could just take a square zero extension of your original ring with some torsion EM spectrum. You do know now that there are homotopy operations, but these are hard to manage. I don't know of a reference other than the section of the $H_{\infty}$ ring spectra volume by Bruner. A copy is on May's website.

Comment: For any space $X$, the composite $$MU \to KU \to F(X_+, KU)$$ gives with a complex–oriented $E_\infty$–ring spectrum whose formal group law is multiplicative. Feeding in, e.g., a Moore space for X will get you plenty of torsion. This isn't a killer example though, as these are augmented $KU$--algebras, and the augmentation cleanly separates the torsion from your other hypotheses. Still something you should disallow. // A recent result of Mathew, Naumann, and Noel (arXiv:1403.2023) gives some control over the behavior of torsion in $H_\infty$ settings. You may enjoy reading their main results.

Comment: @SeanTilson: But it would rule out torsion in $R_0$, wouldn't it? Could you provide some more details for your argument? Does every $E_{\infty}$-ring spectrum containing an element that annihilates the unit have to be a wedge of EM-spectra? Thank you.

Comment: @UlrichPennig There are very precise conditions which Steinberger spells out on page  of 67 (of the text) http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/h_infty.pdf. It definitely does not rule out torsion in general. If you have prime torsion then you know that the underlying module must split as a wedge and so all of the additive $k$-invariants have to vanish, this doesn't mean that you can't build interesting algebras. However, we know what the complex orientations of EM spectra are, and so that might rule out your case. I recommend looking at the article Eric linked to, they are clever fellas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have given yourself an invertible element $u\in\pi_2(R)$ and a coordinate $x\in R^2(\mathbb{C}P^\infty)$ with $\psi(x)=x\otimes 1 + 1\otimes x + ux\otimes x$.  This means that the class $m=1+ux\in R^0(\mathbb{C}P^\infty)$ satisfies $\psi(m)=m\otimes m$.  In other words, $m$ can be regarded as a map of ring spectra from the ring spectrum $T=\Sigma^\infty_+\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ to $R$.  Snaith defined an element $v\in \pi_2(T)$ and proved that $T[v^{-1}]$ is equivalent to $K$.  You are also implicitly assuming that $x$ restricts to the standard generator of $\widetilde{R}^2(\mathbb{C}P^1)\simeq R^0(\text{point})$.  I think that this means that $m_*(v)=u$, which is invertible, so $m$ induces a ring map $K=T[v^{-1}]\to R$.  Under plausible additional assumptions, this map $K \to R$ will in fact be $E_\infty$.  Thus, $R$ will always be a $K$-algebra, and probably an $E_\infty$ $K$-algebra.  The non-$E_\infty$ version could also be extracted from the standard Landweber exactness technology, at least up to phantoms.

If we have an $E_\infty$ map $K\to R$ and $R$ is $p$-complete then we can check that $R^0(B\Sigma_p)/\text{tr}(1)$ is isomorphic to $R^0$, and we can use this to define a power operation $\psi^p$ on $R^0(X)$ for all spaces $X$, which is a ring map satisfying $\psi^p(t)=t^p\pmod{p}$.  The existence of $\psi^p$ excludes many possibilities for $R^0$ (or the $p$-completion of $R^0$, if $R^0$ is not already $p$-complete).  For example, the ring $A=\mathbb{Z}[e^{2\pi i/p}]$ does not admit a map $\psi^p$ of the required type.

Comment: Dear Neil, can you say more about the "plausible additional assumptions"?